# I keep getting a null pointer exception whenever I launch an activity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Whenever I attempt to load up my activity I get a null pointer exception and the application crashes the log cat pointed to this code

```
public Cursor getScores() {
    return ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+DATABASE_TABLE, new String[0]);
}
```

and below is logcat

```
02-18 10:12:37.719: E/AndroidRuntime(404): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-18 10:12:37.719: E/AndroidRuntime(404): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.example.connectfour/com.example.connectfour.ScoreActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-18 10:12:37.719: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at       android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)  
02-18 10:12:37.719: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-18 10:12:37.719: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-18 10:12:37.719: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-18 10:12:37.719: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-18 10:12:37.719: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-18 10:12:37.719: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-18 10:12:37.719: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 10:12:37.719: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-18 10:12:37.719: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-18 10:12:37.719: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-18 10:12:37.719: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-18 10:12:37.719: E/AndroidRuntime(404): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-18 10:12:37.719: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at com.example.connectfour.Database.getScores(Database.java:57)
02-18 10:12:37.719: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at com.example.connectfour.ScoreActivity$MyCursorAdapter.<init>  (ScoreActivity.java:21)
02-18 10:12:37.719: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at   com.example.connectfour.ScoreActivity.onCreate(ScoreActivity.java:49)
02-18 10:12:37.719: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-18 10:12:37.719: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-18 10:12:37.719: E/AndroidRuntime(404):
```

Comment: you get `NPE` on `Database.java:57`, check 57th line.

Comment: What is the line number 57 in Database.java

Comment: make sure DATABASE_TABLE is not null and try with: `return ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);`

Comment: Usually you need to open your database before you can access ourDatabase (If you followed the standard Android guideline). Have you opened your database first?

Comment: How do I make sure the database Table is not null?

Comment: i set it to null and it still crashes

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:

```
return ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+DATABASE_TABLE, new String[0]);
```

since you are not passing any parameter, this would be the correct syntax

```
return ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+DATABASE_TABLE, null);
```

**[EDIT (1)]**

but only if you opened your database, first (first means before calling getScores()).

**[EDIT (2)]**

Something like:

```
SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase = getApplicationContext().openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

Comment: still not working 02-18 12:47:22.505: D/dalvikvm(333): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 50K, 53% free 2553K/5379K, external 2730K/3266K, paused 142ms
02-18 12:47:23.486: D/dalvikvm(333): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 53% free 2552K/5379K, external 6764K/8447K, paused 45ms
02-18 12:47:33.555: D/dalvikvm(333): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 11K, 52% free 2583K/5379K, external 8695K/10350K, paused 46ms

Comment: what do you mean opened my database first?

Comment: where can I put that line?    SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase = DBHelper.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);